# Convert multiple ps files in a folder to Adobe PDF using vb.net or c#.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf-generation

Is there any way to convert multiple ps files in a folder to a single Adobe Acrobat PDF.

Here is the sample code am using now

```
pdfDist.FileToPDF(pathOut & "\Ctc\temp.txt", pathOut & "\Temp\Temp.pdf", "No Downsample")
```

upb.txt contains belows script which take all ps files in the folder and trying to convert it

```
/PathName (C:/MyTemp/*.ps) def
/RunDir {
{ /mysave save def
dup = flush
RunFile
clear cleardictstack
mysave restore
}
255 string
filenameforall
} def
PathName RunDir
```

Its working fine with Acrobat Distiller 5.0 , but its not working with Acrobat Distiller 7.0 .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I remember using Acrobat Distiller from C# (been a while) and had a hard time to solve some issues...

Maybe you could use this as a workaround : generate separated PDF files and merge them afterwards with PdfSharp library (http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ConcatenateDocuments-sample.ashx)

Comment: I need Acrobat way itself,because after creating some acrobat plugins are also using by end users, so it needs to support that

Comment: I understand, If you use C#, you can still use acrobat to convert files to PDF because it's just fine for that task and just call PdfSharp to merge the files. PdfSharp would be embedded in your C# program, it does not change anything for users, no additonal installation is required.